# ogr2ogr append 1 row to a File GDB feature class's data table

Tags: file-geodatabase, ogr2ogr, spatial-database, import, append

I export a polygon layer from Oracle to a FileGDB using ogr2ogr. I need to append one row to the data table, with '0' for numeric fields and 'No Elements' for the one string field.  In ArcGIS, I run a model that appends a feature class with the one observation to the target feature class (the one exported from Oracle).

How can I perform the same function using ogr2ogr?  Would I append the 'no_element' feature class to the target feature class, and if so, what is the ogr2ogr syntax?  Both feature classes are in the same File GDB.

Or, is there something I could add to my ogr2ogr syntax when I export my data from Oracle; I've included my ogr2ogr for my Oracle export.

```
     ogr2ogr -update -overwrite -nlt polygon -nln EO_DSMRE  -a_srs EPSG:3089 -progress -f FileGDB G:/Office/Heritage/DataMngt/dpaml_app/KSNPC_Update/DSMRE.gdb OCI:biotics_dlink/XXXXXXXXXXXX@biotics5:EO_SHAPE -sql "select  EO_SHAPE.SHAPE SHAPE,  EO_SHAPE.EO_ID EO_ID, to_char( EO_SHAPE.EO_ID) EO_ID_STR, CASE WHEN (DSMRE_EO_VW.ELCODE LIKE 'P%' OR DSMRE_EO_VW.ELCODE LIKE 'N%') THEN 'Plant' WHEN (DSMRE_EO_VW.HIGHER_TAX_CODE LIKE 'IMGASF%' OR DSMRE_EO_VW.ELCODE LIKE 'IMBIV%' OR DSMRE_EO_VW.ELCODE LIKE 'AF%') THEN 'Aquatic Animal' WHEN DSMRE_EO_VW.ELCODE LIKE 'AMACC%' THEN 'Bat' WHEN DSMRE_EO_VW.ELCODE LIKE 'C%' THEN 'Community' ELSE 'Terrestrial Animal' END TAX_TYPE  from  EO_SHAPE,  DSMRE_EO_VW where  DSMRE_EO_VW.EO_ID =  EO_SHAPE.EO_ID"
```

***Update

I have created a table in the Oracle data base with the fields 'SHAPE, EO_ID, TAX_TYPE'.  The values for these fields are 'NULL, 0, "No Elements"'.  I also created a view of the data that I have been exporting.  Then I tried this:

```
    select no_element_table.* from no_element_table union select shape_table.* from shape_table
```

That did not work, SQL Developer spits out ORA-22901: cannot compare VARRAY or LOB attributes of an object type.

So at this point, now that I have created the 'No_Elements' table, I just -update -append that to the target table.

```
    ogr2ogr -update -append ......
```

Comment: I think you need -update -append.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  But how do I add the extra 'No Elements' observation into the data table, i.e., how do I insert a row?

Comment: Do you need a sub-query to select from Oracle, then have an outer query add fields not in the sub-query?

Comment: No, I do not need to add any fields.  I need to add a NULL observation where I assign a 'No Element' value to the TAX_TYPE field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `union all` will not throw an error.

`ogr2ogr ... -sql "select * from table1 union all select * from table2"`

This eliminates the need to run a second `ogr2ogr` statement appending the null values.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this problem was to create a table in oracle with the NULL value and 'No_elements' for tax_type field.  I then add an extra ogr2ogr line in my batch file that appends the NULL observation into the existing file geodatabase that is exported in the previous line.